# Is it necessary to add String[] args to main method in java, even if I'm sure that I won't pass any command line argument?if yes why?

Tags: java

Is it necessary to add String[] args to main method in java, even if I'm sure that I won't pass any command line argument? If yes, why? And are there any other parameters that can be passed to main method???

Comment: Yes. Because JLS says so. You can alternatively use varargs.

Comment: Yes but you don't have to use it

Comment: By the way, if the sole reason of this question is that you got tired of typing it down everytime, just let your IDE do the job it is designed for (among others, generating code). In Eclipse I just have to type `main` and then `[ctrl+space]` and then `[enter]` to get the whole main method template.

Comment: I've gone to typing `main(String... ignore)` to remind me that I'm not using the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *necessary* to have arguments, but if you give the main method 0 arguments you won't be able to use it as an entry point.  If you take away the arguments it will compile.  For example, this code will compile and run:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //you can run this from the command line
        main(); //you can call the faux main
    }

    public static void main() {
        //you can't run this from the command line
        System.out.println("called");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java Language Specification point  §12.1.4 [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html): "Yes you have to."